# css width 100 percent only cover what is the size of screen (doesnt cover line after scroll)

Tags: css, width

on my css code I set the  background-image:url with

```
height:100%;
```

but as a result, the range that the 100% capture is only the size of the screen.
if the page have a scroll, all the page line needed to be scroll doesn't appear to have those background.

Any suggestions?

NOTE: my element size changes dynamically.

Comment: Well for a start `100%px` is invalid, change to `100%` and see if that improves

Comment: I edited my question to 100% only. but still not work

Comment: Try setting the HTML and BODY tags to also be height:100%

Answer (score 0):

```
body
{
background-image:url('paper.gif');
background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is, because 100% means 100% of your parent element. First of all, make sure your document is actually 100% of your browser window.

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%; /* for older browsers */
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I post that on my css, it works on google chrome but not on firefox :(